# Exim - add footer to all outgoing emails except for one user

Tags: exim, filter

I am currently managing an email server that is being handled by Exim 4.85 This server currently adds a footer to all outgoing messages. The line that adds this functionality can be found on several guides:

```
transport_filter=/usr/bin/altermime --input=- --disclaimer=/etc/exim_footer --disclaimer-html=/etc/exim_footer_html
```

However, it is now necessary to keep certain outgoing emails as they were originally. The advantage is that this has to be done for a single email address, namely `bob@example.com`, and all of these emails will be text-only (ie no HTML).

Example:

```
alice@example.com sends email ===> exim adds footer ===> delivered
  bob@example.com sends email =========================> delivered
```

I figured I could make use of the [string expansion](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-string_expansions.html) capabilities and make `altermime` use a blank file for that but it has been a nightmare so far. I have basically been getting

```
Expansion of [...] failed: condition name expected, but found ""
```

and

```
transport filter process failed (127): unable to execute command
```

What bothers me, is that testing the expansion via the `exim -bem` command returns the desired output.

These are just a few of my failed attempts:

```
transport_filter=/usr/bin/altermime --input=- --disclaimer='${if eq {$sender_address}{bob@example.com}{/etc/exim_footer}{/etc/empty_file}}'
transport_filter=/usr/bin/altermime --input=- --disclaimer=${if eq {$sender_address}{bob@example.com}{/etc/empty_file}{/etc/exim_footer}} --disclaimer-html=/etc/exim_footer_html
transport_filter={${if eq {$sender_address}{bob@example.com}{/etc/empty_file}{/usr/bin/altermime --input=- --disclaimer=/etc/exim_footer --disclaimer-html=/etc/exim_footer_html}}}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set your transport_filter to bash/python/.. script

```
transport_filter = /scripts/exim_add_signature.sh $sender_address
```

See http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-generic_options_for_transports.html for documentation about transport_filter.

In the script do the following (pseudo-code):

```
no_signature_mails = ["bob@example.com"]
if (argv[1] isnotin no_signature_mails)
    /usr/bin/altermime --input=- --disclaimer=/etc/exim_footer --disclaimer-html=/etc/exim_footer_html
```

Comment: Sometimes it's the simple things that work. Thank you very much! I am going to look into further customizations in the future, for example to allow per user footers.